# How to enable handwriting recognition in qt?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qqmlcomponent

[In the image you can see that the HWR button is enabled(green) but the input panel to write using mouse pointer is not coming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXfuw.png)I am trying to run handwriting recognition example(basic.pro) provided by qt.
The application is getting launched with qt virtual keyboard but im unable to see the HWR icon.
Can anyone help me on how to open handwriting recognition in this example?
I have attached the screenshot of the application.

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = basic
QT += qml quick quickcontrols2 xml
SOURCES += main.cpp
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig disable-desktop handwriting lipi-toolkit
static {
    QT += svg
    QTPLUGIN += qtvirtualkeyboardplugin
}

target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/virtualkeyboard/basic
INSTALLS += target

RESOURCES += \
    demo.qrc

OTHER_FILES += \
    Basic.qml \
    basic-b2qt.qml \
    content/AutoScroller.qml \
    content/HandwritingModeButton.qml \
    content/TextArea.qml \
    content/TextField.qml \

disable-xcb {
    message("The disable-xcb option has been deprecated. Please use disable-desktop instead.")
    CONFIG += disable-desktop
}

disable-desktop|android-embedded|!isEmpty(CROSS_COMPILE)|qnx {
    DEFINES += MAIN_QML=\\\"basic-b2qt.qml\\\"
} else {
    DEFINES += MAIN_QML=\\\"Basic.qml\\\"
}
```

[In the image you can see that the HWR button is enabled(green) but the input panel to write using mouse pointer is not coming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXfuw.png)

Comment: I can see it! It is right above the keyboard on the right! The grey circle with the white line in it

Comment: In the image you can see that the HWR button is enabled(green) but the input panel to write using mouse pointer is not coming

Answer (score 0):

The handwriting button is above the keyboard to the right.

Comment: In the image you can see that the HWR button is enabled(green) but the input panel to write using mouse pointer is not coming